# How to integrate the Reporter.log("Login failed.") with custom testng report using the IReporter?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have been trying to generate a custom testng report similar to the emailable-report.html which is generated by default in testng. In my test case, I have added reporter.log statement to check the flow of test execution, but these logs are not getting printed in the custom report.
Is there a way to integrate the log statement in the custom report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the messages logged via `Reporter.log()` to show up in your test reports, you would basically need to retrieve them using `Reporter.getOutput(result)` (Here `result` is of type `org.testng.ITestResult`). Invoking this method you would get a list of strings which represents the output associated with that particular `ITestResult` object. You would need to dump these lines into your report.

For a sample, take a look at [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter2.java#L443-L459) section of the `EmailableReporter2.java` from TestNG.